# Katie wants to make a list of songs from her phone , in how many ways can she make one?

Tags: combinatorics

Katie has $m$ songs in her phone, she wants to make a playlist consisting of $s$ songs such that every song is played at least once, and  a song can be played again if and only if at least $k$ other songs have been played in between.

In how many ways can she create such a playlist?

attempt: Let Katie have $m$ songs in her phone such that there are $s$ songs to be played . Suppose $k \leq t$  so that we select $t$ songs from $m$ songs, so that we have $m \choose t$ , then at least $k$ songs implies we have $k$ or more, so we have $m \choose k $ + $m \choose k+1$ + ...+ $m \choose m$ = $\Sigma_{t = k}^m $ $m \choose t$ total ways.
Can someone please verify this is correct? and if it's not, please provide some feedback. Thank you.

Comment: What did you mean by $k\leq t$? You set $t=k$ in your summation, and where did $s$ go?

Comment: I am trying to have that at least $k$ other songs have been played in between. So $t$ be the songs in between.

Comment: I need to choose songs out of $s$ songs?

Comment: So to clarify the question: you have a playlist of $s$ songs from $m$ total songs, and every single song has the property that you must play $k$ or more other songs before repeating a song (where k is a constant), and that each song must be played at least once?

Comment: Your playlist is $s$ songs long, so for every $s$ there is possibly a different number of playlists.

Comment: yes. there are a total of $m$ songs and a playlist with $s$ songs out of the $m$ songs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55804/discussion-between-jason-chen-and-mahidevran).

Comment: Can you tell us the source of the problem?

Comment: Seems like an infinite number of playlists. An example, 5 songs a-e, playlist of 3, must have two songs between. abcabcabcabcabcabc... any length you want.

Comment: @Arby: But the playlists are required to be of length $s$. The question is how many different playlists are possible, given input data $m,k,s$.

Comment: it's a made up problem I don't know where it comes from because it's not from the book we use in class. We use Bona's book from combinatorics

Comment: Have you worked out any specific examples? $m=5$, $s=3$, $k=2$ songs a,b,c,d and e gives the following lists: abc, abd, ..., cde of which there are $\binom 53$ assuming order is not important. $m=5$, $s=3$, $k=1$ is more interesting. aba, bab, aca, cac,...,ded,ede,abc,...,cde which gives $\binom 5 2+\binom 5 3$ if I'm not mistaken. Edit: Looking at the original solution in the problem, they *almost* match.

Comment: Who is this Katie?

Answer (score 1):

Let $m,s$ be positive integers, and let $k$ be a nonnegative integer.

Let $f(m,k,s)$ be the number of playlists of length $s$ from a collection of $m$ songs, with the restriction that if a given song is replayed, there must be at least $k$ other songs between the play of the given song and the replay.

Then $f$ is given by the following piecewise formula:

$$
{\small{\bullet}}\;\;\text{If $s \ge k+1$ then}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
$$

$$
f(m,k,s) =
\begin{cases}
\left({\large{\frac{m!}{(m-k-1)!}}}\right)(m-k)^{\large{{s-k-1}}} & \text{if $m >k$}\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\;\,\\[6pt]
\;\;0 & \text{otherwise}\\[6pt]
\end{cases}
$$

$$
{\small{\bullet}}\;\;\text{else if $s < k+1$ then}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\,
$$

$$
f(m,k,s) =
\begin{cases}
m!/(m-s)! & \text{if $m \ge s$}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\\[6pt]
\;\;0 & \text{otherwise}\\[6pt]
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score -1):

For m = 3, s = 5 and k = 1. The above answer gives 48. But the correct answer is 42. If the three songs are A, B and C. Then the playlists like ABABA and ACACA should be subtracted from the count since not every song is played at least once.

P.S I do not have credit to add a comment for the above answer. That's why added as a separate answer.

Comment: When $m = 3$, $s = 5$, and $k = 1$, the answer is indeed $\binom{m}{k + 1} (m - k)^{s - k - 1} = \binom{3}{2} 2^3 = 48$. Also, please try to write a clear derivation instead of providing broad ideas.